# If function is measurable on an interval, is it measurable on its subinterval?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

This is exercise 2.3 from "A User-Friendly Introduction to Lebesgue Measure and Integration" by Gail S. Nelson:

Let $[c,d]\subseteq[a,b]$. Show that if $f$ is measurable on $[a,b]$, then $f$ is measurable on $[c,d]$.

By definition, function $f$ is Lebesgue measurable on an interval $I$ if for every $s\in\mathbb{R}$ the set $\{x\in I\mid f(x)>s\}$ is a Lebesgue measurable set. Here, obviously $\{x\in[c,d]\mid f(x)>s\}\subseteq\{x\in[a,b]\mid f(x)>s\}$, but at the moment I don't see how to proceed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$E=\{x\in[c,d]\mid f(x)>s\}=\{x\in[a,b]\mid f(x)>s\}\cap [c,d]$ so $E$ is measurable being the intersection of measurable sets.

Comment: Thanks for answering to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Since $[c,d]\subseteq[a,b]$, we have:
$$
\Big( x\in[a,b]\ \&\ f(x)>s \Big)\ \&\ x\in[c,d]\quad\text{if and only if}\quad \Big( x\in[c,d]\ \&\ f(x)>s \Big).
$$
Therefore
$$
\{x : x\in[a,b]\ \&\ f(x)>s\} \cap [c,d] = \{x: x\in[c,d]\ \&\ f(x)>s\}.
$$